# How to get a particular row from a DataRow[]?

Tags: c#

```
DataRow[] headerRows = null;

headerRows = mappingTable.Select("FieldID LIKE '0_%'");     //mappingTable is of type DataTable.
```

I have three columns in the mappingTable `"Id","Display", "Value"`

Now, I need to get the `Value` where `"Id" = 0_0_0` from the headerRows.

Is there any simple way to do this?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks everybody for showing different ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use DataRow[] then with linq you can do this:

```
String value = (String)rows.Single(
    row => String.Equals(row["Id"], "0_0_0"))["Value"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `PrimaryKey` on the `DataTable` and then you can use `Find()` on the `Rows` collection to find the row with that key.

```
dataTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataTable.Columns["Id"] };

object value = dataTable.Rows.Find("0_0_0")["Value"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ: but this might be overkill:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<object>("FieldId").StartsWith("0_"));
```

If you have to have DataRow[] then

```
headerRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<object>("FieldId").StartsWith("0_")).ToArray();
```

From there you have only data rows that match your criteria, so you can cycle through for the value.